# Avaya Aura 8.1 SMGR with WebLM

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm preparing Avaya Aura 8.1 components on KVM for the first time as a "pre-installation" setup in the test lab. I'm running on the test licenses so I'm not able to open the ticket on Avaya and sometimes documentation is not clear or enough...

My virtual machines:

- CM
- SMGR
- WebLM
- SM

I've successfully configured WebLM's VM IP to the CM but I don't know where to connect SMGR and WebLM. And more, I found out there is probably an integrated WebLM within SMGR because I can see WebLM menu from the SMGR's dashboard (Services>Licenses) and the Primary Host ID is different from the one in WebLM VM.

Questions:

1. Does SMGR have an integrated WebLM and my VM is not needed (at lest for small installations)?
2. In case if I'll keep dedicated WebLM, where to connect it to the SMGR (I don't want to ask for new licenses) if possible?

Answer (score 0):

So I found answers ...

1. yes, SMGR (at least KVM version) has own WebLM and everything is working
2. Standalone Avaya WebLM is not supported on Session Manager KVM OVA ... so I can't go with this option and this question is not valid anymore